# rounded button image - scaling doesn't looks good

Tags: xcode, macos

I have an image of a button with rounded corners.
When I resize it (using auto-layouts) it doesn't looks so good.
If I'm trying to slice it (via xcode assets) it's shape looks better, but since the button image has some types of green, the slicing not working so good (you can see color differences when it's sliced).

Any other solution to be done here?

Comment: You should never resize components with images, it will distort.. rather try to create/draw the design if not complex.

Comment: isn't that the reason we have slicing?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom button class with rounded corners

```
class GameButton: UIButton
```

Then in layoutSubviews

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
  self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
}
```

Comment: sry - I changed the question tag, I need it for OSX - it's different there

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the CornerRadius to button layer and use that image. That could do better. Don't resize the image.